# How do I find the most used branches in git?

Tags: git

Lets suppose it's my first day on a company with many teams (I haven't yet met) working on a Git repository. I still don´t know the git branching model, but I would like to explore the repo. The teams are maybe working on some feature branches, new releases, etc. I would like to know the most important branches of the repo.

A possible approach would be to find branches with recent activity and old starting points.

Another approach could be a rendered image of the commit history (maybe summarized) where I can visually see the branch evolution.

Any ideas?

Comment: I use `git log --graph --decorate --branches`.  If you've got `less` installed on your system you can pipe to that for mouse scrollability: `git log --graph --decorate --branches --color=always | less -r`.  That's a nice visual way to view the history and get a sense of what branches are important.

Comment: Also consider [git show-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch), handy tool for have a visual overview.

Answer (score 0):

```
git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all --since=90.days.ago # 'last.week' or whatever
```

and check whether you've got the repo devs push to.